# How to display on Angular 6 Frontend the images stored on the laravel .env configuration path?

Tags: angular, laravel

I want to display the passport images of Wife and Husband in one of my edit page where front end is angular 6 and backend is Laravel 5.5.44. I don't know How to take that src path ( to give in img src) of the front end.
I have a .env file with the files upload path as

My folder structure isthis:

[image]

Here 
"ERP_Project" is the Server side laravel code

"Erp_UI"  is the front end angular 6 code

"Uploads" is the folder where images stored according to the .env configuaration of laravel

`APP_UPLOADS_URL=http://localhost/Uploads`

How I can pass the url path of the file to the front-end ?

Comment: Put an API call From Front End (Angular 6) to the server (Laravel) and get the URL, After the angular components loaded.

Answer (score 0):

with blade directives you can use php `{{ CODE }}`

then you could access the env variable this way `{{ env('APP_UPLOADS_URL', 'default/path/if/env/dont/work) }}`

Comment: I need to take the url of the file in format of http://localhost:8000/    for giving on <img src > tag on front end , not in blade .... How it can ?